# IE conditional comments being picked up by Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

i am using the following cc's, i have a few issues with :before layout for gt-ie8 that i want to target

```
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class='ie ie8 lt-e9 lt-e8'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class='ie ie9'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html class='ie gt-ie9'> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html class='not-ie'>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

my problem is that FF and chrome both pick up the .gt-ie9 class. I have been using html5bp and i am trying configuration from browserhacks.com

Comment: How does it "pick up" the class? A quick test with a style based on the class shows no such thing in FF or GC.